# Update not working if @version colum is added to pojo. It inserts a new record instead

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA with Spring

If I add @VERSION as one of the colums in my POJO .... my record is not getting updated instead inserting a new one .... but if I remove it [ @VERSION ] it works perfectly in a sense updating correctly .. Cant seem to find any thing ... as there are no errors and I need to add the VERSION column any how

Comment: Post some code, configuration, usage code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, I did not mentioned the VERSION column as a variable in my Bean, And me scenario was that I was taking an old record from database to Controller and changing certain values and then updating it I am using DOZER to this. So while updating DOZER was not finding any VERSION variable in BEAN and hence it was setting it to NULL again, So when I call the update method it takes VERSION as NULL and defaults it to 0 and instead of UPDATE does a SAVE again.

If mentioned VERSION in both POJO and BEAN the problem will be solved.